# Cannot install android apk on my real device

Tags: android, adt, android-install-apk

I got this error when installing my developed apps to my android phone

```
[2013-11-13 11:06:11 - Test] ------------------------------
[2013-11-13 11:06:11 - Test] Android Launch!
[2013-11-13 11:06:11 - Test] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-13 11:06:11 - Test] Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-11-13 11:06:13 - Test] Uploading Test.apk onto device '087A4C7CF209'
[2013-11-13 11:06:13 - Test] Installing Test.apk...
[2013-11-13 11:08:15 - Test] Failed to install Test.apk on device '087A4C7CF209!
[2013-11-13 11:08:15 - Test] (null)
[2013-11-13 11:08:15 - Test] Launch canceled!
```

I am sure the debug mode is on, I tried to cancel and reset it, no luck. The device can be detected so I am sure it's fine in that regard

```
$adb devices
List of devices attached 
087A4C7CF209    device
```

If I install it from the command line, it hangs there and never return success.

```
$ adb install ~/workspace/Test/bin/Test.apk 
3096 KB/s (255979 bytes in 0.080s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Test.apk
```

UPDATE

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

IT JUST WON'T WORK!! what can I do? Please help I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: can you show your manifest file and android version on device ?

Comment: @nilkash, manifest file updated. android version is 4.1.2

Comment: A few suggestions that might work: restart your environment (could be there's an error in the code that isn't showing up), make sure there isn't another version of the app installed on your device, or try killing adb and restarting it, export the app and email it to yourself and download it from your email to device and see if it installs that way.

Comment: I have restarted basically everything-- Eclisp ADT, phone, adb server, debug mode...This is killing me

Comment: Try installing on a different device. If it does get installed then there is some problem with the first device.

Comment: This sounds like a environment problem. Try cleaning your project, sometimes stale data will show up in the APK and can cause these issues.

Comment: @NandakishoreK, I tried on another machine, which worked. so I guess it's my phone's bad. Any way I can trace the bug?

Comment: Just found that my phone cannot even install any app from google play, or apk file copied from my computer. So I guess my phone is in seriously bad state. How can I address this problem?

Comment: Factory reset the phone. If that does not solve the issue, then flash the phone with stock rom.

Comment: factory reset the phone solved the problem. Big thanks @NandakishoreK

Answer (score 0):

Make sure install from unknown sources is checked in application manager settings,if it didn't help try following:

1. make sure you have installed google USB driver/ OEM driver
2. make sure usb debugging is checked on your device
3. make sure you have enough space on your phone
4. try changing minimum sdk version (it worked for me)

Comment: No. I am sure it's the phone in trouble. So please suggest with regards to phone